# Lambda as OutputIterator

Tags: c++, c++11

I come from the Java world and am not too experienced with C++, so the following question has come up. I see that `OutputIterator` is used quite extensively. What I have seen so far is that people use an inserter, such as `std::back_inserter`.

Is it not possible to somehow provide a lambda which is called for each element instead of recording the elements in a container?

#### Example:

Instead of

```
std::vector<int> my_vector;
set_intersection(s1.begin(), s1.end(), s2.begin(), s2.end(), std::back_inserter(my_vector));
```

something like

```
set_intersection(s1.begin(), s1.end(), s2.begin(), s2.end(), to_iterator([](int x) {
    std::cout << x;
}));
```

Comment: For this particular use case, you may want to try [`std::ostream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator) ([demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/59a332bed45701d2)).

Comment: Using ostream_iterator, however, quickly become impossible once you are out of the sandbox. The inability to insert delimiters only in-between the elements is a deal breaker for any kind of sane usage.

Comment: @SergeyA: So use an [infix iterator](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/13176/489).

Comment: @JerryCoffin, it is not dificult, hard or time-consuming to develop your own outstream iterator with expected functionality. The thing is, STL was created for exactly the same reason - to provide a standard implementation for something which is not hard to do yourself, but you would need it in virtually any application. It would probably take me about no more than a day to implement any of STL containers, except maybe hash map - solely because of hash function - and around 1 hour to implement any algorithm, besides sort. Same with infix itr - SHOULD BE STL!!!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Boost has `function_output_iterator` for this purpose:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/53b4582b0ec7e4dd)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/function_output_iterator.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

int main() {
    std::set<int> s1{ 1, 2, 3 }, s2{ 3, 4, 5 };
    set_intersection(s1.begin(), s1.end(), s2.begin(), s2.end(),
                     boost::make_function_output_iterator([](int x) { std::cout << x; }));
}
```

Prints:

```
3
```

It shouldn't be too hard to write a simplistic version of this (although I'd prefer to use `boost::iterator_facade<>` myself so you'd still be stuck with boost)

Answer (score 2):

> Is it not possible to somehow provide a lambda which is called for each element instead of recording the elements in a container?

A lambda, by itself, won't be enough as an argument to `std::set_intersection`. You'll need wrap it in a helper class (functor) that supports the [requirements of an OutputIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/OutputIterator).

The crucial operators that an `OutputIterator` must support are `*iter`, `iter++`, and `++iter`.

Comment: Not just `*iter`, but specifically `*iter = val;`